# Escrita otimizada de trecho em javascript (semântica)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, pessoal!

Gostaria de saber a maneira correta de escrever esse simples trecho de JavaScript:

Ao clicar na div ".mais", todas as divs ".conteudo" estão se expandindo.

Qual a semântica correta de escrita para que um click na div ".mais" do id="linguagens" não execute a ação na div ".conteudo" de id="codigos" e "frameworks" e vice e versa.

```js
$(".mais").click(function() {
  $(".mais").fadeOut()
  $(".menos").css("display", "flex")
  $(".conteudo").css("max-height", "60rem")
});

$(".menos").click(function() {
  $(".menos").fadeOut()
  $(".mais").css("display", "flex")
  $("#conhecimentos .conteudo").css("max-height", "0")
});
```

```html
<div id="linguagens">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Linguagens</h2>
    <div class="expand">
      <div class="mais">
      </div>
      <div class="menos">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <p>exemplo
    <br>exemplo
    <br>exemplo
    <br>exemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="codigos">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Codigos</h2>
    <div class="expand">
      <div class="mais">
      </div>
      <div class="menos">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <p>exemplo
    <br>exemplo
    <br>exemplo
    <br>exemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="frameworks">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Frameworks</h2>
    <div class="expand">
      <div class="mais">
      </div>
      <div class="menos">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <p>exemplo
    <br>exemplo
    <br>exemplo
    <br>exemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece por conta a hierarquia da estrutura HTML,

Caso seu HTML seja fixo, digo a estrutura dele, você pode usar algo semelhante a isso:

```
$(".mais").click(function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this.parentElement.children[1]).fadeIn();
  $(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).css("max-height", "60rem");
  $(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).fadeIn();
});

$(".menos").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).hide();
  $(this.parentElement.children[0]).fadeIn();
});
```

Nesse link tem um exemplo funcional

https://jsfiddle.net/jvt9g8a4/

Comment: Usar algo como `$(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1])` é extremamente não DRY, um tormento para manter quando o HTML mudar, e dificil de ler... tenho de dar `-1` porque acho mesmo isso uma má ideia...

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar a o elemento com a classe `.expand` para procurar o outro mais/menos em combinação com o `.closest`.

Outra opção é usar o `.siblings` do jQuery para encontrar o outro elemento, partindo do principio que há só 2 elementos descendentes de `.expand`: um `.mais` e um `.menos`.

Nesse caso o código poderia ficar assim:

```js
$(".mais, .menos").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut().siblings().css("display", "flex");
  var abrir = $(this).hasClass('mais');
  $(this).closest('.titulo').next().css("max-height", abrir ? "60rem" : "0");
});
```

```css
.conteudo {
  max-height: 0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linguagens">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Linguagens</h2>
    <div class="expand">
      <div class="mais">
      </div>
      <div class="menos">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <p>exemplo
      <br>exemplo
      <br>exemplo
      <br>exemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="codigos">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Codigos</h2>
    <div class="expand">
      <div class="mais">
        +
      </div>
      <div class="menos">
        -
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <p>exemplo
      <br>exemplo
      <br>exemplo
      <br>exemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="frameworks">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Frameworks</h2>
    <div class="expand">
      <div class="mais">
        +
      </div>
      <div class="menos">
        -
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <p>exemplo
      <br>exemplo
      <br>exemplo
      <br>exemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente contribuição, Sergio! Muito obrigado. Mas a dúvida principal é como fazer  com que a ação seja realizada em apenas 01 div  ".conteudo" e não em todas.

Comment: @Will é isso que o meu código faz. Usa a relação entre elementos no DOM para agir somente sobre um `.conteudo` e não todos. Testaste o meu exemplo?

Comment: @Will respeito que aceites a resposta que melhor resolve o teu problema. Mas a resposta que tens aceite vai dar muita dor de cabeça caso o HTML mude 1 milimetro... está demasiádo customizada e é uma dor de cabeça só de ver...